# birthday or anniversary occured during date range vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Good afternoon members,
I would like to make birthday viewing in a database a function

the following information is given with the function

```
class person

public property dateofbirth as nullable(of datetime)

end class


public function allperson() as Ienumrable(of preson) implements databank.allpersons

return _contact.values.oftype(of person).orderby(function(c) c.name)

end function




   public function birthday (startdate as date, Enddate as date) as IEnumerable (of Person) Implements databank.birthdaybetween


/.... ???

    end function
```

**here is a picture of my problem
http://s8.postimg.org/vn4ufpmqt/problem.png**

thanks
Elisa

Comment: This is not "quite" the same as birthday-paradox (refering to tag)

Comment: @Elisa: Please be more specific on what you expect as the result of the birthday method. Some examples with data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the birthday function should return all the persons who celebrate their birthday in the timeframe between startdate and enddate, the following query should work:

```
    Return (From x In allperson() _
        Where x.DateOfBirth.HasValue AndAlso x.DateOfBirth.Value.Year <= startdate.Year 
            AndAlso ((startdate.Month = x.DateOfBirth.Value.Month AndAlso startdate.Day <= x.DateOfBirth.Value.Day) _
               OrElse (startdate.Month < x.DateOfBirth.Value.Month)) _
            AndAlso ((x.DateOfBirth.Value.Month = enddate.Month AndAlso x.DateOfBirth.Value.Day <= enddate.Day) _
               OrElse x.DateOfBirth.Value.Month < enddate.Month)).AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: I've updated my sample so that it also works for the nullable DateTime DateOfBirth.